# Define a Typescript type from properties of objects in a list

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have a list of objects like:

```
const TABS = [
  {
        name: 'Home',
        // other properties
  },
  {
        name: 'Profile',
        // other properties
  }
];
```

How can I define `type Tab`, which is a type for the 'name' field of each object in the list? Basically the equivalent to

```
type Tab = 'Home' | 'Profile';
```

in the case above (but without the need to repeat "Home" and "Profile" in both definitions).

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/4w1nON) meet your needs?  If so, I'll write it up as an answer.  If not, please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible as long as the value of `TABS` is known at compile time and you prevent the compiler from widening its type to something like `Array<{name: string}>`.  You want the compiler to remember the specific [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) of the values you put into the `name` properties, and not just treat them as `string`s.  The easiest way to do this is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the `TABS` array literal at creation time:

```
const TABS = [
  {
    name: 'Home',
  },
  {
    name: 'Profile',
  }
] as const; // <-- need this
```

Now the compiler knows that `TABS` is a pair of objects and that the first one has a `name` property of the string literal type `"Home"`, and that the second one has a `name` property of the string literal type `"Profile"`.

At this point you can just use [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to get the `name` property of the elements at the numeric (`number`) indices of the type of `TABS`:

```
type Tab = (typeof TABS)[number]["name"];
// type Tab = "Home" | "Profile"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgQQEIGUYF4YG0BQMYDee+MYAhgLYCmAXDAOQASI19ANMQL4f5EmmVaDAAoAnEADMAlgBsq7LjgC6MMhBihIUANwwA9HpgAeALQnSVKgBMYUABZT1OAyFHxkaAO6yZMAEZUMFJgElSiotaq6gjhZACeRgTk1HTQosEA5pwAfKpgNhKuGVSwZH4gAK6waZkwMlJQYWQyEDg4UHEADoFwZRgwABQd3ZLuqACUWGAVFAGiSlgARMlUi0razobDPX2Yi8zUizAAPjCLYpKyq0A)